# Map host user into postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers

I was trying to run postgres 12.0 alpine with arbitrary user in an attempt to have easier acces to the mounted drives. However, I get the following error. I was following the instructions from official docker hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

> docker run -it --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro postgres:12.0-alipne

I get: initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted

Then I tried initializing the target directory separately which needs a restart in between. This is also not working and gives me the same error. But this time, the container starts as a root user.

Has anyone had success running the postgres alpine container with an arbitrary user?

Comment: PostgreSQL stores its data in a pretty opaque format, so there's not a lot of benefit to having the files be owned by your host user (even if you could mechanically read the files it'd be hard to extract meaning from them).  What are you trying to accomplish, that you can't with the default user ID?

Comment: I am trying to bind mount container-host directory so that data is persistent and I can have a backup; for example PITR. If I am trying to access those data on my host, every time I need to own the data or change the permission which is a bit convoluted workflow.